# How to check last char is { in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript

I want to create a `{}` completion myself, and I did:

```
inoremap <CR> if_open_curly_on_left()? <CR>}<ESC>O : <CR>
function! s:if_open_curly_on_left() abort
    let col = col('.') - 1
    return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '{'
endfunction
```

which is modified by other's code, since I don't really understand the meaning inside the function.

When I typed enter I got:

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is wrong here:

```
getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '{'
```

This is saying *anywhere* before my cursor do I have a `{` character.

Probably want something that says does the *end* have a `{` character

```
getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '{$'
getline('.')[col - 1] == '{'
```

Although in theory that could still be weird if you put your insert cursor between `{}` characters and hit `<cr>`. So I imagine this needs to be adjusted a bit to become more robust

Maybe you the logic and be something like:

```
col('.') == (col('$') - 1) && strpart(getline('.'), -1) == '{'
```

This will check that your in the final column and it ends with `{`

**Aside**:

> Why `col('.')-2` to get the previous character?

TL;DR: column position is 1-indexed and strings/arrays are 0-indexed

`col('.')` give you the current cursor position with the first column being `1`

`getline('.')` will return a string or an array of characters with the first index being `0`

Assume the following line and you cursor on the `r`:

```
bar
```

So if we do a `getline('.')` and split it e.g. `split(getline('.'), '\zs')` we get:

```
['b', 'a', 'r']
```

Since we are on the `r` character then `col('.')` gives us `3` which is outside the bounds of our array by one. We compensate for the column starting on position one by subtracting one, `col('.') - 1`, to give the current position. To give the "previous character" then subtract by `2`

Comment: By your kind hint at last line(, after many try-and-error), I got: `return line[col] != '}' && line[col-1] == '}'`. Regarding the original one, why it's `col-1` in `getline('.')[col-1]` when I already did `let col = col('.')-1`?

Answer (score 1):

After some search this work(, but might be simplified further):

```
" My try
inoremap <silent><expr> <CR>
    \ <SID>if_open_curly_on_left()? "\<CR>}\<ESC>O":
    \ "\<CR>"
function! s:if_open_curly_on_left() abort
    let col = col('.') - 1
    return getline('.')[col - 1] == '{'
endfunction
```